# X-cart migration to latest version without loosing database

Tags: php, x-cart

Our website is currently using `X-cart` version 4.4. We want to upgragde to version 5.0. The coding standard, file structures, and database tables are completely different. So we have to migrate `X-cart` 4.4 database into `X-cart` 5, then make new skins according to `X-cart` 5 standard and all modules installation as well as customization.

How do we upgrade without loosing the existing database?

Comment: I've improved the grammar and spelling of the post. However, it's still not 100% clear what question you're actually asking. I've attempted to pull the question from your title and embed it in the post, please confirm that my assumption was correct.

Comment: Maybe just focus to `xcart_customers` table, usually you do not need anything else. Once I just merged orders counter for each user into new database, but really you do not need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The general X-Cart 4 > X-Cart 5 migration guide is here:
http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Migration+from+X-Cart+4+to+X-Cart+5

You can migrate your data using paid service of cart2cart:
http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/migration-from-x-cart-4-to-x-cart-5

If you contact X-Cart sales team at sales@x-cart.com, you will receive a discount voucher that will allow you to migrate some part of your data for free (up to 5000 products, 2000 users and 5000 orders).

You can also migrate your store to X-Cart 5 using commercial service of X-Cart team:
http://www.x-cart.com/x-cart-migration.html